# What could be causing the 'unauthorized_client' error when retrieving email body from Gmail API in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, gmail-api

I'm facing an issue with fetching email data using the Gmail API in my NestJS backend. My goal is to retrieve the body of an email message and display it on the frontend of a website. Additionally, I need to create a new file and store the fetched data in that file.

However, I'm encountering an error message that states:
**[Nest] 14920 - 05/21/2023, 5:20:30 PM ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to create access tokenError: unauthorized_client. **
I have already double-checked my .env file and the connection with the Gmail API, and everything appears to be correct.

Could you please assist me in understanding why I'm getting this 'unauthorized_client' error? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights to help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

I have already double-checked my .env file and the connection with the Gmail API, and everything appears to be correct.

Comment: Hello, hard to say without seeing any code.